# Why there are no solutions to $ x'(t) = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{if $x$ is rational} \\ -1, & \text{if $x$ is irrational} \end{cases}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Why there are no solutions to any initial value problem for this equation

$$ x'(t) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x$ is rational} \\
-1, & \text{if $x$ is irrational}
\end{cases}$$

?

The solutions are $x=\pm t+c$.

Comment: The derivative of $t+c$ is $1$ whether $x$ is rational or not. Similar thing goes for $-t+c$.  Note that $\pm t+c$ is not a function.

Comment: Derivatives can't have jump discontinuities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative of a real-valued function must have the intermediate value property (aka must be a "[Darboux function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis))"), but your righthand side does not have this property.

As for your proposal, $x=\pm t+c$ is not even a function. Perhaps you mean

$$x(t)=\begin{cases}t+c & t\in\mathbb{Q}\\-t+c & t\in\mathbb{Q}^c\end{cases}$$

but then $x$ isn't even continuous, much less differentiable.

Comment: I saw the answer of this exercise here http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/tmcmillen/M310/hw/HW09_sol.pdf and I thought it was correct (whitout understand it)

Comment: @Isabella: what is your comment supposed to mean? The answer you link to is not rigorous. The phrase "this is impossible" needs to be justified, and the talk of "increasing" and "decreasing" is, strictly speaking, wrong, since the sign of the derivative only tells you about whether a function is increasing and decreasing if the derivative has the same sign over an interval, not just at a point.